# Showing Date incorrectly on the lightning input

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

I am showing date default value as today's date in a format DD/MM/YYYY and the format is coming correctly as well. But on the LWC Html it is not showing correctly.

Please find the attached screenshot

[image]

**HTML Code**

```
 {formattedDate}
<lightning-input type="date"  value={formattedDate} data-name = "StartDate" onchange={handleDateChange}> </lightning-input>
```

**JS Code**

```
let today = new Date();
this.defualtDate = today.toISOString();
this.formattedDate = this.formatDate(this.defualtDate);
console.log(this.formattedDate);

formatDate(date){
    let dateObj = new Date(date);
    let day = dateObj.getDate();
    let month = dateObj.getMonth()+1;
    let year = dateObj.getFullYear();
    return `${day}/${month}/${year}`;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `date-style` attribute as short `short` of `lightning-input`.

```
<lightning-input name="input1" label="Enter a date" type="date" date-style="short" />
```

*Note : The component uses `date-style="medium"` by default to display the date in a medium-length style, such as Jan 7, 2020 in the en-US locale. To display a short style such as 1/7/2020, set date-style="short" in the component. To display a long style such as January 7, 2020, set date-style="long".*
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input/documentation